# How to indicate end of spiccato?

Tags: theory

How should I indicate the end of a spiccato section in the following situation? I do not want to leave it up to the interpretation of the string player.

Let's say the first measure of a phrase has the marking "spicc.".  I want the spiccato to continue for several measures, so on the second measure I mark it with "sim.". Keep in mind, most of the notes are sixteenth or eighth notes. How do I indicate to stop playing using the spiccato technique? I know "arco" isn't very suitable since the player is already using their bow, but in a specific way.

Comment: See the answers to this similar question: [How to notate going from staccato to "normal"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122133/how-to-notate-going-from-staccato-to-normal)

Comment: Note, if you've used the text direction _spicc._, I don't think you need to add _sim._; it's understood to continue. You can use _sim._ if you indicated the spiccato with staccato dots, and you could do both—dots, plus "sim" to mean they continue, plus "spicc" to specify the bowing technique more narrowly.

Comment: This question was closed, but my suggestion does not really fit the similar question, so I’m linking this. If you really want to be specific and precise you might want to do something like this http://petzel.at/spiccato.png